# how to select option of selection box using for loop

Tags: jquery

hi can anyone tell me what should i write so that on every iteration of for loop option's value changes and i get one by one option's value. following is the code:

```
for (var i=1; i<4; i++)
 {
   $("#mydropdown_for_month option[value=i]").attr('hidden','hidden'); 
 }
```

for example dropdown has 10 values but i want to hide those options which have the values dynamically changed by for loop so i write " option=i " but it is not working. I mean i want to write variable i. how can i do that

Comment: $('#mydropdown_for_month option[value="+i+"]").attr('hidden', 'hidden');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `i` as a variable:
 [EDIT 2] Thanks to ThiefMaster, here is a nicer code :

```
for (var i=1; i<4; i++) { 
   $("#mydropdown_for_month option[value=" + i + "]").prop('hidden', true);
}
```

[EDIT] Without *hidden* attribute (which exists only in HTML5) - thanks to Phil and ThiefMaster:

```
for (var i=1; i<4; i++) { 
   $("#mydropdown_for_month option[value=" + i + "]").hide();
}
```

Comment: There is no attribute `hidden`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: correct, thanks ! i just copy-pasted the code from the OP. i'll correct it

Comment: Actually, the HTML5 `hidden` attribute probably has a property behind it, so you could use `.prop('hidden', true)` which is nicer than setting an attribute with a nonsense value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try, `$("#mydropdown_for_month option").eq(i).hide()` didn't test it, just a guess :D

Comment: this would probably work if the options are in the same order as their values. But indeed, that would be smarter

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"option=" + i
```

So that the 'i' is a variable rather than a string

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a loop here (actually, loops are quite rare when you're using jQuery in the way it was designed for).

You can use the [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to match a subset of the `<option>` elements and hide them all at the same time:

```
$("#mydropdown_for_month option").slice(1, 4).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1; i<3; i++)
 {    
   $("#mydropdown_for_month").find('option[value="'+i+'"]').hide();

 }
```

here is the demo  http://jsfiddle.net/DBXGe/